# How to solve "index is out of bounds" for multi-band image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, k-means

I am trying to create a feature vector from an image with 8 channels. The image was already converted to `numpy array` and its size is `(8, 22096, 17771)`. I am using the following code but I receive an error that `index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8`. I will use the feature vector for kmeans clustring. Can anyone help to solve this?

```
rows= 22096
cols= 17771

featureVectors= []

for i in range(0, rows, 1):
    for j in range(0, cols, 1):
        vector = [arr_image[i][j]]
        for k in range(0, len(arr_image)):
            vector.append(arr_image[i][j])
            featureVectors.append(vector)
```

---

if the feature vector is created by `featureVector=arr_image.flatten()`, it gives the following error in kmeans clustring. please see below:

```
scaler_d = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

scaler_d.fit(featureVector)
featureVectors = scaler_d.transform(featureVector)

kmeans_d = KMeans(n_clusters=13, random_state=170)
kmeans_d.fit(featureVector)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

result = centers_d[labels]

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[23 34 32 ... 58 54 59].
```

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Couldn't `range(0, rows, 1)` be simplified to `range(rows)`?

Comment: You are indexing the first dimension of `arr_image` using `i`, but `i` goes from `0` to `22095`, once it gets to `8` it throws an error because you have gone past the first dimension of `arr_image`.

Answer (score 0):

I’m a bit confused what you are doing here, do you want a feature vector for each channel? Or for the whole image?

If you want one feature vector for the whole image, use `featureVector=arr_image.flatten()`. If you want one for each channel, you can use `featureVectors = [chan.flatten() for chan in arr_image]`.

Comment: I want the feature vector for the whole image, and later I need to use it for the kmeans clusting. If I use featureVector=arr_image.flatten(), can I use it as an input to kmeans clustring?

Comment: @rayan I suppose you could, assuming you have many other images with the same dimensions that you want to analyze with k-means. K-means clustering wouldn’t make much sense with just one feature vector. Edit: I don’t know the greater scope of your project, but you might want to look into PCA to get more meaningful results from k-means.

Comment: Please see the updated question.